# Is an Arduino microcontroller capable of detecting its own pins that are connected with each other?

Tags: arduino, microcontroller

I have a matrix and I want to connect it directly to Arduino without using IC.

I want that whenever I connect two pins in Arduino microcontroller, example: pin1 and pin2, the microcontroller will automatically detect that pin1 and pin2 were connected. All pins were input pins. Can an Arduino do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect two pins on an Arduino. But it isn't clear what you trying to do or why.

Since both pins are input, you can detect any changes on the pins in software - the only way to detect that anything is connected to a pin of course is for an electrical signal to change on that pin. When it does, you will detect that in software and take actions accordingly.

You can also connect an output pin to an input pin. Not much use of course unless you have some other circuitry that does something interesting between the two pins.

UPDATE: The thing to remember is that these cheap microcontrollers have minimal protection from overvoltage and high current. But as long as you do not exceed the specifications of the chipset (which will be one of the Atmel chips, the Uno uses the [ATmega328](http://www.atmel.com/dyn/resources/prod_documents/doc8161.pdf) for example), you will be fine. The Atmel chips are reasonably robust and will happily work between 1.8 and 5.5v (not sure what max. current the pins support though). So just make sure your circuits are within parameters.

Comment: Thank you @Julian Knight for this comment.  I just need to know if this is possible because i'm afraid it might destroy the microcontroller

Comment: Ok @Julian Knight. A big thanks for this update. I just have to be extra careful on my circuits then and make sure it does not exceed the specifications of the chipset.

Comment: No worries, the Arduino's are pretty lenient - unlike the Raspberry Pi.